# Problems accessing Spring-Boot RestController from Angular frontend

Tags: angular, maven, spring-boot

I have the following setup:

**My controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/project")
@RestController
public class ProjectController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/createProject")
    public ResponseEntity createProject(@RequestBody ProjectDto projectJsonString) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**In my `.service.ts`:**

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/project/createProject', JSON.stringify(project)).
      subscribe( (res) => {
        this.logger.info('Response: ' + res);
      });
```

**My Dto:**

```
public class ProjectDto {
    private String projectName;
    private String projectNumber;
    private String projectArea;
    private String managerName;
    private String managerShorthand;
}
```

But when I build the app to a jar-file and execute it I get the following error when the api-call is executed:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/project/createProject", ok: false, …}
error:
error: "Unsupported Media Type"
message: "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
path: "/project/createProject"
status: 415
timestamp: "2018-12-10T21:41:26.036+0000"
```

and the same thing happens when I `curl` it. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is ‘createProject’ in the url? I don’t see mapping for that. Just use http://localhost:8080/project

Comment: @Lemmy Sorry, I see my class still contains the const for that url, I will update it. It is the mapper of my method - I saw the first problem, I used `name` instead of `value`, thanks for that!

Comment: I understood that but I am saying that you don’t have mapping for createProject. Use value instead of name. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Comment: remove stringify because you have to send json

Answer (score 1):

The error "Unsupported Media Type" happens when the request does not include an appropriate Content-Type header.

Please make sure your requests contains "Content-Type" header with the value "application/json" (assuming your sent data is in Json).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by HL'REB, you should add the correct Content-Type to your post request, as you are using spring boot and RestControllers I Assume the default json support is activated so probably this is the Media Type expected(`application/json`).

So you could try the following change

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/project/createProject', JSON.stringify(project), 
{ 
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
}).subscribe( (res) => {this.logger.info('Response: ' + res);});
```